# Can I use a JFormattedTextField with a MaskFormatter without placeholder text?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, formatter

I would like to have a text field which only allows six numeric characters and formats them with a space in the middle. Currently I am using something like this:

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("###' ###");
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
field.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
```

The problem is that before the user has entered any text, the text field contains seven spaces. I would like the text field not to contain any characters that have not been typed by the user.

I have tried `formatter.setPlaceholder("")` in the hope that the placeholder character would be the empty character. However, this doesn't seem to work, and even if it did, I imagine the space in the middle of the field, stipulated by my format, would still be there from the start.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?.

Comment: One way is with a regular JTextField whose document has a DocumentFilter attached.

Comment: as per what I see from the java docs You still need an InputVerifier for JFormattedTextField. ""JFormattedTextField allows the focus to leave, even if the currently edited value is invalid. To lock the focus down while the JFormattedTextField is an invalid edit state you can attach an InputVerifier. ""  You can simply use JTextField with a DocumentFilter

Comment: also have you tried setValue for your field. Like this 
JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField();
   tf.setValue(new Number(0)); This is to say that you have it initialized. Also if you use filter action you can automatically add a space in between.